# OKTA - not able to retrieve authorization code

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, okta, okta-api

I am trying to get the authorization code from the redirect URI using below endpoint but all all I am getting is an HTML Page as part of the response . I need to get the authorization code from the api response. When I use Postman, I could see the below value as part of response headers location.

```
https://oidcdebugger.com/debug/?code=H9QD-knUSRO-xqXI4AQA&state=IL'
```

But I am not sure how to get the above value from my code . Below is my code snippet, can someone help me on this.

```
Const options = {
    followRedirect: true,
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://dev-XXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize',
    qs: {
        client_id:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
        "response_type":'code',
        scope:"openid",
        sessionToken:"20111nGGrl17go5apfKtY-nwcFSemP1VdMJaqT5ceGQpbOIhJ1eq9US",
        "redirect_uri":"https://oidcdebugger.com/debug",
        "state":"IL",
        nonce:"XXX"
          },
    headers: {
        'Accept':"application/json" ,
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
             }
  }

request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("**********************response***************************************");   
   console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("**********************error***************************************");   
    //console.log(err.options);
    console.log(err.response.req.path);
  });
```

Comment: What's the question here? Are we likely to need to see some code? Probably. Maybe check out [how to ask the perfect question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can refine yours a little bit to make it easier for us to answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

the "https://dev-XXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize" is a front end REDIRECT call. The endpoint redirects you to your redirect url "https://oidcdebugger.com/debug" so it is expected. you need to have supply a callback function/endpoint as your redirect URL so when the above endpoint it called the callback function will have the code.